# 'autoAttachChildProcesses' option not doing anything

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a javascript program that launches a script inside it with the following command:
`node --inspect file.js`.
When it happens, I would like VSCode to auto attach debugger to the child process. This is my config in launch.json:

```
 "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Start with Yarn",
            "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
            ...
        }
```

auto attach is set to 'SMART'.

So I launch the program with the configuration, wait for the script to get called inside the program and... VSCode does not automatically attach a debugger to it. Why is that?

Comment: It sounds like you are starting a new Node process and not a child process if you're running a command like that inside a node script. Child processes are launched like this: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html